# Lifecycle of calls when using the SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewImage 

Tags: android, android-imageview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

OK, trying to get images from my SD card to show in an activity `ListView`.

I'm reading lots of hints, but I'm missing an important chunk. I'd love to see a short-ish bit of source code that illustrates this, haven't found anything yet.

From my research it sounds like `bindview()` is called when `listview.setadapter(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter)` is executed. The documentation says that `setImageView` is called by `bindview` if the `ViewBinder` cannot handle an `ImageView`.

You specify the field in the `FROM` array, the `id` of the `TextView` in the `TO` array, the `Cursor`, and the view group with the `TextView`. Then set the adapter to the `ListView` and voila, it happens.

I think the call sequence is then:
`listView.setAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter)->adapter.bindView()->adapter.setTextView`

Bindview must determine the view is of type `TextView, determine that it can bind it, passes the`TextView`and text value from the cursor and`setTextView` does its thing.

So, that makes the call for an `ImageView` very similar, right?

```
listViw.setAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter)->adapter.bindView()->adapter.setImageView
```

So when `bindView` comes across and object of type `ImageView`, what does it do? Is there a default implementation like in `setTextView`? I'd imagine it would be hard to do that, images vary so much. Text is text, but images have formats, sizes, depths, scale, LOCATIONS, etc, etc. The string passed to the `setTextView` IS the text, the payload. In an image the string is (probably) the filename, only the starting point of an image.

I think I'll need to build my adapter with the database column name that holds the filename in `FROM`. The `TO` array will have just the id of the `ImageView` in my layout. I think I can use the default viewbinder *bindview()*, but will have to override `setImageView()` to take the expected string (filename), and build out the image loading lines to find that image name in the expected application path.

So that will be (maybe):

```
listView.setAdapter(MyOwnSimpleCursorAdapter myOwnAdapter)->myOwnAdapter.super.bindView()->myOwnAdapter.setImageView()
```

Does this sound right? If anyone can fill in the missing gaps and/or provide some working source code it would help a lot. By the way, I've written code to do this, but it isn't working. It could be a very simple bug and don't want to stop this thread if it's do-able. I think I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand what is your question(and yes, you should post the failing piece of code) so here is my answer(you can also see this in the source code of the `SimpleCursorAdapter`):

In a `SimpleCursorAdapter` when the `ListView` requires a new `View` to be shown the method `getView()` will be called. This methods delegates the row building to 2 methods: `newView()`(which will create the `View`(inflating the xml layout you've set) and set as a tag an array of the `View`s with the `ids` from the `to` array) and `bindView()`(which will actually bind the data to the `View` created by `newView()`).

`bindView()` will then iterate through the arrays of `View`s(the `View`s with the `id`s from the `to` array) on which to bind the data. It will also call `getString`(and only the `getString` method, this is important) from the cursor to get the data. Next the method checks if a `ViewBinder` has been set on the adapter, if this is the case it will let that `ViewBinder` to set the data(the methods `setTextView()` and `setImageView()` will not be called if the `ViewBinder` successfully binds the data).

If a `ViewBinder` wasn't set on the adapter or the `setViewValue` method of the `ViewBinder` returns `false`(meaning the `ViewBinder` has failed) then the `bindView()` method will check and see which type of `View` it is dealing with(`TextView` or `ImageView`) and call either `setViewText()` or `setViewImage()`.

The implementation of the `setViewImage()` will try to parse the supplied String as an  `int` (example: an image id `R.drawable.image`) and if this fails it will then parse the `String` as an `Uri` and use `setImageUri()` on the `ImageView`. So an `int` like `R.drawable.image` or a `String` like `"file://mnt/sdcard/photo100.jpg"` should work with the default implementation of the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, otherwise override the `setImageView`.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the detailed answer, especially considering my question was hard to find in all that verbiage. The question was kinda sorta "does this sound right?"

I was unaware of the calls to getView() and newView(), but the extra detail on how setViewImage is super helpful. I haven't gone to the source code for answers yet, just the documentation. Another good tip...

Comment: My code also didn't fail, per-se, it just didn't display any images. This is because the strings returned from the database were just filenames, not Uri's, "photo100.jpg" vs. "file://mnt/sdcard/photo100.jpg".

I'll switch to storing the full path of the image, which will be better in case I decide to support images in multiple locations.